# PL/pgSQL , How to make a function using Raise notices and export the messages from the console to a text file from the Code

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have to make a update function that have multiple conditions like this

```
BEGIN
  OPEN cur3 FOR execute('select id_organigramme from ( select distinct  id_personne,id_organigramme,idfax  from requpdate where
    id_personne= ' || VariableIDpersonne || ' and idfax is  null) a where
    a.id_organigramme not in (select distinct   id_organigramme  from
    requpdate where id_personne= ' ||VariableIDpersonne || ' and idfax is
    not null and a.id_personne=requpdate.id_personne )  ');
  LOOP
    FETCH cur3 INTO VariableIDorganigrammeFax;

    if not found then
      --Message here !!!
      --Raise notice 'hello word!'   
      exit;
    end if;
```

I have to show up messages if any condition exists I found out that I can do this with Raise Notice/info ... statement, but I have to make auto export of those messages into a text file when the function finishes.
Is this possible? Otherwise what can I use to make it.

I use PGAdminIII as a client.

Comment: What environment are you using to access the database? A client like `psql` or `pgAdminIII` or some language/framework like Java, C#, Rails, etc? Basically every environment has its own options so please edit your question (use `edit` link under your question) to give us some more information.

Comment: It depends entirely on the client that's accessing the database. `NOTICE`s are out-of-band messages that need to be handled by the client driver, and the application needs to know how to ask the client driver for them.

Comment: So this is a task which you manually run from your PC when you need to, not one which is scheduled to run automatically?

Answer (score 1):

What your logging options are depends entirely on your client configuration. But rather than using `RAISE NOTICE` I would suggest you use the [`NOTIFY` \ `LISTEN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) framework. Basically, in your function you issue a notice to a *channel* of your choosing (can be any string) and in your client you listen to that same *channel*, logging the messages as they come in. How exactly the listening and logging works depends on your client.

The code you show can also you use some improvements.

First of all, your query is an incredibly convoluted version of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_organigramme
FROM requpdate
WHERE id_personne = VariableIDpersonne
  AND idfax IS NULL;
```

Secondly, you do not need a dynamic query, you can get by with variable substitution. Assuming `id_personne` is not a string, it is as simple as stated above, otherwise use `quote_literal(VariableIDpersonne)`.

Lastly, unless there are parts of your function not shown that require a `cursor`, you can simply do:

```
FOR VariableIDorganigrammeFax IN [query above]
LOOP
  ... -- do your processing here
END LOOP;

IF NOT FOUND THEN  -- the loop above did not iterate because no records were returned
  SELECT pg_notify('logMyFunction', format('%s: No records found', VariableIDpersonne));
END IF;
```

The `pg_notify()` function is a wrapper around the `NOTIFY` command that makes it possible to pass variable strings.

Before you call the function, you should issue the command `LISTEN logMyFunction` so that your session will receive the notifications from the channel.

Comment: Thank you your improvement was very helpfull ! the client i use is pgadmin III ,
can you please brief me on the NOTIFY also ?